# How can i transfer phone memory apps to external SD card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

I am getting very low space please help.
I want to install or transfer apps on external SD card completly.

Comment: See also our fine [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for additional ideas concerning your "low space" issue.

Comment: Use app2sd app from play store

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-> Manage Applications->
Select the app-> Move to SD Card